# Function for taking a integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I made a function to take intergal Likehood(L,U,gamma,sigma), but there are some error.
Here is my Matlab code.

```
function func=Likelihook(L,U,gamma,sigma)
Lstar=3;
Ustar=20;
gammastar=1.5;
a=0.2;
func=-0.5.*log(2.*pi)-log(sigma)+log(gamma)-log(L.^(-gamma)-U.^(-gamma))+quad(@(y)(log(quad(@(x)(x.^(-gamma-1).*exp(-0.5.*((y-x)./sigma).^2)),L,U)).*gammastar./(sqrt(2*pi).*Lstar.^(-gammastar)-Ustar.^(-gammastar)).*quad(@(x)(x.^(-gammastar-1)./(a.*x).*exp(-0.5.*((y-x)./(a.*x)).^2)),Lstar,Ustar)),-inf,inf) ;
```

And here is the function i want calculate

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP1lz.png

Anyone help me?

Comment: what error do you get? and what's your input?

Comment: That is:
Likehook(2,3,4,5)
??? Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

Matlab tries to compute the integration vectorially, so

```
f = @(x) x;
quad(f(x) x,1,5)
```

gets evaluated like

```
sum(f(1:dx:5))
```

with matlab figuring out what the discretization interval should be.
This is computable, because  `f = @(x) x` takes vectorial input.

When you have a double integral, you'll get something like this:

```
f = @(x,y) x+y;
quad(quad(f(x,y) x,1,5),4:10)
```

becomes

```
sum(sum(f(1:dx:5,),4:dy:10))
```

This will only evaluate if `1:dx:5` and `4:dy:10` happen to have the same number of elements (not very likely).

### Solution

You can solve it of course, by adapting your function `f` so it does take any two vectors as an input, for example by using arrayfun.

For your problem, this is done like this:

```
func = -0.5.*log(2.*pi)-log(sigma)+log(gamma)-log(L.^(-gamma)-U.^(-gamma)) ...
+quad(@(y)( ...
    log( arrayfun(@(z) quad(@(x)( x.^(-gamma-1).*exp(-0.5.*((z-x)./sigma).^2)),L,U), y) ) ...
    .* gammastar./(sqrt(2*pi).*Lstar.^(-gammastar)-Ustar.^(-gammastar)) ...
    .* arrayfun(@(z) quad(@(x)( x.^(-gammastar-1)./(a.*x).*exp(-0.5.*((z-    x)./(a.*x)).^2)),Lstar,Ustar), y) ...
),-inf,inf) ;
```

I inserted some linebreaks (`...`) for easier reading :)

### Remarks

I'm not sure if this will lead to solid results for you, because of the integration from `-Inf` to `Inf`: in the [documentation of quad](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html), it is stated that

*If the interval is infinite, [a,Inf), then for the integral of fun(x) to exist, fun(x) must decay as x approaches infinity*

so, you'll have to make sure that this is the case, otherwise you'll keep getting `NaNs`

Comment: For example,
Likelihook(1.,3.,2.,3.) = NaN?

Comment: but anyway, we can replace inf by 100.